# Games for Windows Live - Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: windows-8.1, gaming

I'm having some issues with installing Games for Windows Live under Windows 8.1. I'm running a 64 bit OS and I've tried the following steps.

1. Downloaded the gfwlivesetup.exe from Microsoft's Website
2. Set its compatibility to Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows XP SP3, etc all with no luck
3. Tried running it as administrator.

None of this works and no matter what, it ends in an `Error Code: 0x80070660`. I have no other GFWL clients installed or anything.

I have the following logs available:

[My setupexe.log](http://pastebin.com/7DvN2cpN)

[My xliveinstall-elevated log](http://pastebin.com/LhR1pGBr)

If you guys need anymore information I'd be glad to answer. Googling that error code turned up nothing.

Comment: You do know Games for Windows Live sevice was retired over a year ago.  The games that implemented should have been patched.

Comment: @HopelessN00b i've got some older games that still have yet to be patched that's the thing. i have install cd's that won't proceed without it

Comment: Even if you get them to work.  If the games are not patched.  You won't be able to play them.  The server said services were taken offline.

Comment: The patches could be manually installed after; I just need the game to install now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that windows installs games for Windows Live files into a wrong directory (SysWOW64), you will have to move the files to System 32 directory (c:\Windows\System32)After installing Game for Windows Live,
Go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Find these files

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xlive.dll

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xlivefnt.dll

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xlive.dll.cat

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xliveinstall.dll

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xliveinstallhost.exe

And Copy the five files mentioned above to C:\Windows\System32\
And thats it! Any problems with Games for Windows Live must be resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

If you need GFWL for a game (of course, why else would you need it?) and you don't need multiplayer you can download and use a fake xlive.dll from [this site](http://timeslip.users.sourceforge.net/). Works for Bioshock 2 on Windows 8.1.